# In which format should I pass access token if oauth 2 is enabled [Retrofit]

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, retrofit, okhttp

I am using Retrofit for all my api calls in my application. This is the first time I am using it and its very easy to implement.

But my server side has recently updated and they have enabled Oauth 2.

I get an access token in my sign in response which I need to pass in the header.

Please help me to do this, I **know how to pass the values in the header**, but the thing i need to know is, **In what format should I pass the access token**

Please Help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the OAuth 2.0 specification says access tokens can be passed in an Authorization header as in

```
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
```